# Is there a way to get a Linq Query to select a timestamp field encoded as a Base64 string?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, jquery, linq-to-entities

We have a concurrency check field in our database that is a SQL timestamp.

If I am using a razor view with

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DatabaseRowVersion)
```

it encodes to a Base64 string and binds back to my model in the save action fine.

If I get the field by a Json request with

```
Json(queryable.Select(f => new { DatabaseRowVersion = f.DatabaseRowVersion }))
```

then the resulting Json is an 8 field byte array and I cannot get it to bind back to my model in the Save action. Is there some way I can get Linq to Entities to select the field as a Base64 string before it gets serialised?

My solution is a dirty looking JavaScript function to convert 8 field byte arrays to Base64 strings, but this is not pretty and I would rather the original Json request return the field already encoded. Everything I have tried gives me an unsupported Linq to Entities function exception. I don't want to do it in memory, I would like to find some sort of Entities.Functions style of getting it to happen on the SQL server.

Another way I wouldn't mind doing it is if could get jQuery to post the save request in some way that would bind an 8 field byte array to a byte[] back in the model but everything I have tried doesn't work. I have tried all the traditional: true and contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" on the post with no success like with other actions that bind an array in an Ajax post successfully. It just doesn't seem to work like with other arrays as the model binder seems to be expecting a Base64 string rather than a byte array for byte[] fields on the model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are still looking for an answer but I've managed to resolve this by converting the byte array into a string and back:

```
string stringValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteSource);
Byte[] byteValue = System.Convert.FromBase64String(stringSource);
```

For your case you can create a ViewModel and use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to map between your Model (which has the Byte Array TimeStamp) and ViewModel (which would have the String TimeStamp).

Finally you would use your ViewModel to create your view and when updating, you would map your ViewModel back to your Model and update from there. This way your hidden field would be a string and you wouldn't have the issues you are having right now.

Automapper does not have an implicit conversion method between Byte arrays to String so you would have to implement something like this for your converters:

```
public class ByteArrayTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, Byte[]>
    {
        public Byte[] Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            string source = (string)context.SourceValue;
            if (source == null)
            {
                source = "";
            }

            Byte[] returnValue = System.Convert.FromBase64String(source);

            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    public class StringTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<Byte[], string>
    {
        public string Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            Byte[] source = (Byte[])context.SourceValue;

            string returnValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(source);

            return returnValue;
        }
    }
```

And your Mapping initializer would look something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<string, Byte[]>().ConvertUsing(new ByteArrayTypeConverter());
Mapper.CreateMap<Byte[], string>().ConvertUsing(new StringTypeConverter());
Mapper.CreateMap<YourViewModel, YourModel);
Mapper.CreateMap<YourModel, YourViewModel>();
```

Hope this helps.